# AngularJS + PHP Contact Form

Tags: php, forms, angularjs

This contact form has been the bane of my existence for about a week now, any help would be great.

I have my server and controller set up so it will grab my php data and hopefully process the data through php when the form is submitted.

It seems as if the controller is correctly POSTing the data, and that it is received by `proccess.php`, my express, nginx, etc logs confirm this is all looking ok; the data seems to be POSTing ok as well; the issue seems to be in my PHP.

I have it set up to query the data, and return a JSON array confirming success and subsequently mailing the data; or reporting a fail; and for some reason it seems to fail every single time.

here is my controller:

```
mainControllers.controller('ContactCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.formData;
$scope.processForm = function() {
console.log('Im in the controller');
console.log($scope.formData);
$http({
    method  : 'POST',
    url     : '/process.php',
    data    : $.param($scope.formData), 
    headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } 
}).success(function(formData) {
        console.log(formData);
        if (formData.success) {
            console.log('Success');
        } else {

            console.log('Fail');
        }
    });
};
});
```

my php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
require_once 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

if (isset($_POST['inputName']) && isset($_POST['inputEmail']) && isset($_POST['inputPhone']) && isset($_POST['inputMessage'])) {

    //check if any of the inputs are empty
    if (empty($_POST['inputName']) || empty($_POST['inputEmail']) || empty($_POST['inputPhone']) || empty($_POST['inputMessage'])) {
        $formData = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Please fill out the form completely.');
        echo json_encode($formData);
        exit;
    }

    //create an instance of PHPMailer
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->From = $_POST['inputEmail'];
    $mail->FromName = $_POST['inputName'];
    $mail->AddAddress('something@test.com'); //recipient
    $mail->Subject = $_POST['inputName'];
    $mail->Body = "Phone: " . $_POST['inputPhone'] . "\r\n\r\nMessage: " . stripslashes($_POST['inputMessage']);

    if (isset($_POST['ref'])) {
        $mail->Body .= "\r\n\r\nRef: " . $_POST['ref'];
    }

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        $formData = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
        echo json_encode($formData);
        exit;
    }

    $formData = array('success' => true, 'message' => 'Thanks! We have received your message.');
    echo json_encode($formData);

} else {

    $formData = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Please fill out the form completely.');
    echo json_encode($formData);

}
```

and html:

```
<form id="myform" name="myForm" data-abide role="form" ng-submit="processForm()">
  <div class="formData.inputName-field">
    <label>Your name <small>required</small>
      <input type="text" name="formData.inputName" id="formData.inputName" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" ng-model="formData.inputName">
    </label>
    <small class="error">Name is required.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="formData.inputEmail-field">
    <label>Email <small>required</small>
      <input type="email" name="formData.inputEmail" id="formData.inputEmail" required ng-model="formData.inputEmail">
    </label>
    <small class="error">An email address is required.</small>
  </div>

  <div class="formData.inputPhone-field">
    <label>Phone #
    <input type="text" name="formData.inputPhone" id="formData.inputPhone"required pattern="^([0-9]( |-)?)?(\(?[0-9]{3}\)?|[0-9]{3})( |-)?([0-9]{3}( |-)?[0-9]{4}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{7})$" ng-model="formData.inputPhone">
    </label>
    <small class="error">Please enter your number in the format '123-456-7890'.</small>
    </div>
    <div class="formData.inputMessage-field">
    <label>Message
    <textarea name="formData.inputMessage" id="formData.inputMessage" ng-model="formData.inputMessage"></textarea> </label></div>
  <button type="submit" class="columns small-centered">Submit</button>
  <div class="panel">
<p>{{formData}}</p>
<p>{{codeStatus}}</p>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: And where exactky does it fail ? What does the response look like ?

Comment: I added a few logs to try and pinpoint the issue, one is called in the controller at `if (formData.success) {
                console.log('Success');
            } else {
                // if successful, bind success message to message
                console.log('Fail');
            }`
the other is in the php file at `else {

        $formData = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Please fill out thsdffe form completely.');
        echo json_encode($formData);

    }`

Comment: So within the .success(function(formData) block as well as the second `$formData =` block of the php... Also, I tried tinkering with the php to do away with validation and saw 'empty string' (I believe that was the message'..Here are screens from the console showing the Response and POST tabs respectively; http://gyazo.com/6046ac608bd42ef4b8797950cf69f1e6 http://gyazo.com/5188e4b02a2aba85b14193b23e062b9f it appears the data is POSTed correctly but it seems as if the PHP is not interpreting the formData as intended.

Comment: Try to `var_dump($_POST)`. What does it look like ?

Comment: changing my php file to `<?php
var_dump($_POST);` produces     `array(0) {
}`

Comment: What version of AngularJS and jQuery are you using ?

Comment: AngularJS v1.2.19 and jQuery JavaScript Library v1.11.1

Comment: I tried it and it works fine :/ What versin of PHP are you using ? Try removing the PHPMAiler stuff and see if it works.

Comment: Hey, are you loading jQuery before AngularJS ?

Comment: ya, jQuery is getting loaded before AngularJS

Comment: So my project was built on top of the yo angular-fullstack generator, I simplified things and tried running a php development server from the client folder, works no problem; the only issue now is none of my scss is being compiled correctly as the previous configuration was an express server launch through grunt, and proxying php to nginx.. anyways, I did figure out how to get the original issue to work, now just a matter of getting it to work within my project; or restructuring the whole thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone still interested, I had to configure express to properly handle PHP using php-express, like so:

```
var phpExpress = require('php-express')({
    binPath: '/usr/bin/php' // php bin path.
});

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.engine('php', phpExpress.engine);
  app.set('view engine', 'php');
  app.all(/.+\.php$/, phpExpress.router);
};
```

Then in my controller I was able to pass along the form data with:

'use strict';

```
angular.module('contactApp')
  .controller('ContactCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $state) {
    $scope.formData;
    $scope.processForm = function() {
    $http({
        method  : 'POST',
        url     : '/process.php',
        data    : $.param($scope.formData),  // pass in data as strings
        headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
    }).success(function(formData) {
            console.log(formData);
            $state.go('success');
        }).error(function(formData){
            if (formData.success) {
                console.log('Success');
            } else {
                console.log('Fail');
                $state.go('contact_err');
            }
        });
    };
    });
```

and a **process.php** that looks like:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
require_once 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

if (isset($_POST['inputName']) && isset($_POST['inputEmail']) && isset($_POST['inputPhone']) && isset($_POST['inputMesage'])) {

    //check if any of the inputs are empty
    if (empty($_POST['inputName']) || empty($_POST['inputEmail']) || empty($_POST['inputPhone']) || empty($_POST['inputMesage'])) {
        $formData = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Please fill out the form completely.');
        echo json_encode($formData);
        exit;
    }

    //create an instance of PHPMailer
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->isSMTP();

    //Enable SMTP debugging
    // 0 = off (for production use)
    // 1 = client messages
    // 2 = client and server messages
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

    //Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

    //Set the hostname of the mail server
    $mail->Host = 'email.host.com';

    //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
    $mail->Port = 587;

    //Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

    //Whether to use SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

    //Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
    $mail->Username = "email@sender.com";

    //Password to use for SMTP authentication
    $mail->Password = "passwordredacted";
    $mail->setFrom = $_POST['inputEmail'];
    $mail->addAddress('example@recipient.com'); //recipient
    $mail->Subject = $_POST['inputName'];
    $mail->Body = "Name: " . $_POST['inputName'] . "\r\n\r\nMessage: " . stripslashes($_POST['inputMesage']) . "\r\n\r\nPhone: " . stripslashes($_POST['inputPhone']) . "\r\n\r\nEmail: " . stripslashes($_POST['inputEmail']);

    if (isset($_POST['ref'])) {
        $mail->Body .= "\r\n\r\nRef: " . $_POST['ref'];
    }

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        $formData = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
        echo json_encode($formData);
        exit;
    }

    $formData = array('success' => true, 'message' => 'Thanks! We have received your message.');
    echo json_encode($formData);

} else {
    var_dump($_POST);
    $formData = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Please fill out the form completely.');
    echo json_encode($formData);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said it seems to work fine but for some reason the fail function is called every single time.

If you look at your code, you call the $http.success function, and *inside* this you have the check for a success again.

As you're most likely to check for the correct return from the $http response, you should use the .success and .error functions directly on the $http, and not inside the $http.success. Have a look at this:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'}).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  // this callback will be called asynchronously
  // when the response is available
}).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  // called asynchronously if an error occurs
  // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

So try moving your fail code from inside the .success function to the .error function and see how that goes.

For further readings: check https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Since they always return `status 200` from server, this won't help solving the issue. It is a good idea to catch errors (e.g. for when the server might be down or the network connection lost), but it has nothing to do with the problem in the question.

Comment: I see, sorry it looks like I misunderstood it

Comment: Thanks for the input @ChrisPreston probably a good idea to follow that format in general but unfortunately the issue seems to lie within the PHP, at least that's what all signs are pointing to at the moment

Answer (score 0):

erase the surrounding if else statement.  There another problem: is not loading the phpMailer class.